# How to make sessions persistent in Scalatra?

Tags: scala, tomcat, servlets, jetty, scalatra

I have a webapp using the Scala-based [Scalatra](http://scalatra.org/) web framework. The problem is, anytime the application is re-deployed, or anytime the app-server is rebooted, all session data is lost. This means (to name one downside) users must re-login every time we make an update to the site.

Some research reveals there are, apparently, "container-specific" ways to make sessions persist across app and server reboots (e.g., [in the case of Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts)), but this has two shortcomings:

1. If the app is not always deployed in the same container (and in the case of Scalatra, an embedded Jetty is used for dev purposes) then I'll need separate configuration for each container.
2. Using a server-local configuration file is much more fickle -- it's likely to get lost in server migrations, and it won't be automatically available to each instance (e.g., to each developer) of the app, whereas something stored with the core application code is much easier to test, retain, and generally keep track of.

So, to sum up...

- Is there a generic, container-neutral way to make sessions persistent? Even if only by overriding appropriate methods in the Java/`Servlet` stack and storing the session data manually?
- Barring that, is there a way to store relevant configuration for multiple containers (e.g., for both Jetty and Tomcat) in my application code (`web.xml` or similar)?

Thanks -- any insights appreciated!